# How to write a condition to ignore some code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know please how to write a condition to ignore an event (the uploading of a file) in react. I want to check if "formData" is empty, if it is, then ignore the axios.post. Tried using << if (formData =="") >> but didn't work. Please help
Here's my code :

```js
onFileUpload = (event) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append(
            "file",
            this.state.selectedFile,
            this.state.selectedFile.name
        );
        //console.log(this.state.selectedFile);
        const oHeaders = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token").valueOf("token"),
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }

            {axios.post(Config.CONFIG_SERVER + "files/uploadFile", formData, { headers: oHeaders }).
                then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data.fileDownloadUri)
                    if (res.status == 200) {
                        this.setState({ path: res.data.fileDownloadUri })
                    } else {
                        toast.error('Echec de chargement du fichier !', { autoClose: 3000 });
                    }
                })}
    };
```

Comment: Check the value in console and use that, for example if it says null, use null.

Comment: `formData ==""` is always going to be false because formData is an object. But you could do if(this.state.selectedFile.name) { axios.post}

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating an instance of FormData, and assigning it to formData const, you need to check if formData is empty.

Your approach does not work, because FormData will not be == to '', it's not a string, it's an object.

Just console log it:
[image: formData object]

**To check if formData is empty** you can check length of its keys.

```
if(Object.keys(formData).length === 0)
```

[image: formData object keys]